# Python : Mouse click coordinates as simply as possible

Tags: python, matplotlib, mouseevent, coordinates

I'd like to code an interactive Bezier curve generator, the only inputs being the mouse click coordinates on a graph (with matplotlib.pyplot)

Thus, I'd like to know how to get these coordinates and how to stack them in two lists for x-axis and y-axis using `class` and `self.functions` as simply as possible.

Thank you !

Bipattes

Comment: If you're not willing to learn a core part of the language, people are not going to be very willing to help.

Comment: @AlexHall Then I'd like to know how to code this using classes, but as simple as possible : i'm starting to understand how classes work.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's an [event](http://matplotlib.org/users/event_handling.html) in matplotlib that returns you mouse coordinates when clicking over a plot. Check the following recipe:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class LineBuilder:
    def __init__(self, line,ax,color):
        self.line = line
        self.ax = ax
        self.color = color
        self.xs = []
        self.ys = []
        self.cid = line.figure.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self)
        self.counter = 0
        self.shape_counter = 0
        self.shape = {}
        self.precision = 10

    def __call__(self, event):
        if event.inaxes!=self.line.axes: return
        if self.counter == 0:
            self.xs.append(event.xdata)
            self.ys.append(event.ydata)
        if np.abs(event.xdata-self.xs[0])<=self.precision and np.abs(event.ydata-self.ys[0])<=self.precision and self.counter != 0:
            self.xs.append(self.xs[0])
            self.ys.append(self.ys[0])
            self.ax.scatter(self.xs,self.ys,s=120,color=self.color)
            self.ax.scatter(self.xs[0],self.ys[0],s=80,color='blue')
            self.ax.plot(self.xs,self.ys,color=self.color)
            self.line.figure.canvas.draw()
            self.shape[self.shape_counter] = [self.xs,self.ys]
            self.shape_counter = self.shape_counter + 1
            self.xs = []
            self.ys = []
            self.counter = 0
        else:
            if self.counter != 0:
                self.xs.append(event.xdata)
                self.ys.append(event.ydata)
            self.ax.scatter(self.xs,self.ys,s=120,color=self.color)
            self.ax.plot(self.xs,self.ys,color=self.color)
            self.line.figure.canvas.draw()
            self.counter = self.counter + 1

def create_shape_on_image(data,cmap='jet'):
    def change_shapes(shapes):
        new_shapes = {}
        for i in range(len(shapes)):
            l = len(shapes[i][1])
            new_shapes[i] = np.zeros((l,2),dtype='int')
            for j in range(l):
                new_shapes[i][j,0] = shapes[i][0][j]
                new_shapes[i][j,1] = shapes[i][1][j]
        return new_shapes
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.set_title('click to include shape markers (10 pixel precision to close the shape)')
    line = ax.imshow(data) 
    ax.set_xlim(0,data[:,:,0].shape[1])
    ax.set_ylim(0,data[:,:,0].shape[0])
    linebuilder = LineBuilder(line,ax,'red')
    plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
    plt.show()
    new_shapes = change_shapes(linebuilder.shape)
    return new_shapes

img = np.zeros((100,100,3),dtype='uint')
shapes = create_shape_on_image(img)[0]
print(shapes)
```

It's a bit extensive (you can also check one of the [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/examples/event_handling/pick_event_demo.html) examples) but it allows you to visually see the places where you are clicking (you can put an image instead of the "black" numpy array for the background). The result should be like this:

[image: mouse click markers in matplotlib plot]

Originally it was made for the shape to be closed but adapt to your needs. Once you close the plot you'll have a `print` for the actual coordinates:

```
[[54 13]
 [19 39]
 [19 77]
 [58 78]
 [93 45]
 [90 11]
 [54 13]]
```

If you prefer to start with something more modest (a simple click event to print coordinates to the console) use this recipe:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def onclick(event):
    print(event.xdata, event.ydata)

fig,ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(range(10))
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)
plt.show()
```

Comment: That last paragraph is gold. I suggest putting that to the start of your answer so people see it sooner